# Build a chat application in ios using XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am trying to build a chat application in ios. I came across [XMPP](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS) for ios. I am bit confused on how to move forward. Here are my doubts:

1. Do I need to create an XMPP server to implement this application?
2. Or are there any existing servers/services which can be used for the same purpose?

Comment: are you done with your app? I understand the part of how to setup the server (or use the publicly available server), but what's next? How to proceed then with the app? Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, XMPP library you found above is perfect to integrate chat in any iOS devices. Coming to your questions .

1. Ideally yes, you should create your own XMPP server so that you have control over it plus there is security issue. A very popular XMPP server is [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/). ejabber is awesome :)
2. Its not must that you need to setup your own XMPP server. You can use some open-source [XMPP servers](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/). Depending on your use-case you can decide.

hope this helps...

Comment: i want to use open source .can you give some detail about that

Answer (score 5):

Your question is confusing because you say "create" when you probably mean "host."

You certainly do not need to develop your own.  You can set up one of many available XMPP servers, a fairly extensive list is [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/).  There are both commercial products and open source ones.

There are also many [publicly available](http://xmpp.net/) ones that you can use.  Two of the more popular today would be Google's gtalk and Facebook chat.

Your own use case is what really determines which path you should take.  For publicly available servers all the users would have to be registered with those domains to use them.