# Private message to friends via iOS app Facebook API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

There are some similar post here on SO but most of them are confusing. Some posts say you can't send via Graph API but Open Graph etc etc.

There was post that FB restricted publishing on user's walls via FB SDK from March 2012.

I am just interested to send message to user's FB friends from iOS App. Which method can be used, is it allowed?

Comment: try XXMP server inorder to send message to particular user

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850619/build-a-chat-application-in-ios-using-xmpp

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via the graph api to send messages. This was removed some time ago due to potential abuse.

They do have though the XMPP/Jabber interface which does however have limitations that a message would not have.

Comment: Can you post to friend's wall using Open Graph API?

Comment: You can no longer post directly to a friend's wall using the graph API. The only way to post to a friend's wall now is by using the Feed Dialog. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/